# How to understand the statement of printf(str+9)?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
char *str="CQUESTIONBANK";
clrscr();
printf(str+9);
getch();
}
```

The output is BANK. what the printf statement does. Can anyone please explain that?

Comment: pointer artithmetic. shifts string by 9 bytes.

Comment: `str+9` shifts the pointer to the 9th character of the string. If you do `str+0` then complete string _CQUESTIONBANK_ gets printed. If you do `str+1` only _QUESTIONBANK_ gets printed.

Comment: Uninstall Turbo C and then get a decent book about C.

Comment: @Lundin `clrscr();` gave him away right ? :)

Comment: ...and the `void main()`

Answer (score 1):

A *string* in C is defined as a sequence of `char` terminated by a `'\0'`. A string isn't a type in C. So, functions handling strings accept a pointer to the beginning of the string (a pointer to `char`).

You can do arithmetics on pointers. `+ x` means increase the pointer by `x` elements pointed to. So, `str+9` in your example points to the character `B`. This pointer is passed as the start of the string to `printf()`.

Answer (score 0):

str gives the base address of the pointer to the string.
So normally if you just use `printf(str)` it should output CQUESTIONBANK.
But in this case you are printing str+9, ie. `printf(str+9)`, so in this case it refers to string starting from the 9th index. In this case the 9th index is B,(C follows 0 indexing), so the string printed is BANK.

printf will always print the string from the passed pointer as starting position till the end of the string, which is stored as `'\0'` known as Null Character. If you try `printf(str[13])`, it should print `'\0'`

Answer (score 0):

`str` points to a location (address). You can move in any direction over these addresses using `+` and `-`. So, if `str` points to some address, say `0x1002`, then `str+1` points to `0x1003` and `str-1` points to `0x1001`. (assuming `str` is `char*`. With other pointer types you move in bigger steps - `sizeof(*str)`)

In your example - `str` points to an address that holds `CQUESTIONBANK` so if you move the pointer 9 steps forward, you move past `C,Q,U,E,S,T,I,O,N` and you now point to `BANK`. Now using `printf` will print from that location resulting in `BANK`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
char *str="CQUESTIONBANK";

/* clrscr() function will clear the console.*/
clrscr();

/* printf() function, outputs the data. The name of the string, in your case
   it is 'str' always points first element of the string which is 'C'. Adding 9 will
   'str' point to 'B' character in the string. That's why printf is printing from B on wards.
   Similarly adding 10 to 'str' will print from 'A' and so on.*/

printf(str+9);

/* getch() function waits for you to enter any character.*/
getch();
}
```

Comment: Thank you all...who made me clear about this...now i understood